# I have problems with Slider's inside a PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview, flutter-slider

I have a number of setup pages inside a PageView. Se example page.

On some of these pages I am using Slider's.

This works quite ok on IOS but on Android sliding the value does not slide the value but instead the page. I.e. the slider is useless.

On IOS sliding outside one of the edges and back leads to sliding the page instead of sliding the value.

Does any one have a suggestion how to overcome this if possible?

Or do I have to forget using Slider's inside PageView pages?

Note: I could of course skip the PageView but being able to swipe through the setup pages is great user experience.  Yea perhaps I have to give up on on that instead!?

[image: Setup page example]

Comment: Can you include  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes I can ... but right now I dont have the time :-)